# Junit test of method with Scanner and System.in (Java)

Tags: java, junit, java.util.scanner, system.in

I'm new to programmming and I have this simple method:

```
public double input() {
        double result = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            result = scanner.nextDouble();
        } else {
            System.out.print("Please, type numbers!\n");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The question is how to simulate (emulate) user's input from the keyboard in junit test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a `Scanner` as input parameter to the method you want to test.
In your test code, you can create a `Scanner` instance from a string:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("the sample user input");
```

And then in the production code, you can pass `new Scanner(System.in)` to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about [dependency injection](http://jasonpolites.github.io/tao-of-testing/ch3-1.1.html).

> Your Class shouldn't be tightly coupled with other classes. Dependencies can be provided to objects at multiple levels according to the need.
>
> 1. Using constructor/setter if it is a field.
> 2. Using method parameters if the scope is just in a method.

In your case as soon as you say:-

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Now your code is fully coupled with `System.in` stream. Instead you should inject this as a parameter to your method in below format.

```
public double input(InputStream inputStream) {
    double result = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
    if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        result = scanner.nextDouble();
    } else {
        System.out.print("Please, type numbers!\n");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now from your main code you can call it with `System.in`. From your test class you call it with any InputStream. Mostly we use a `mock/stub` for it.

**Note:-** Above it just an example, and can be change according to need.